# Django set range for integer model field as constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model,

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    qty = model.IntegerField()
```

where I want to set constraint for `qty` something like this,  >0 or <0,i.e the `qty` can be negative or positive but can not be 0.

Is there any straight forward way to do this in Django?

Comment: You will have to create a custom validator

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use [Django's built-in validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators) -

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    qty = models.IntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(1)]
     )
```

**NOTE:**

1. The validators will not run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on the fields that are included in the form. Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) for more info.
2. To enforce constraints on a database level refer to [maertejin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265698/2932244) below.

Comment: What if my validation list is [2, 5, 7]?

Comment: Maybe [`int_list_validator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#int-list-validator)

Answer (score 7):

Since Django 2.2 you can enforce the constraints on a database level with [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint):

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    qty = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=models.Q(qty__gte=1) & models.Q(qty__lt=10),
                name="A qty value is valid between 1 and 10",
            )
        ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You will have to create a custom validator

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_number(value):
    if something :  # Your conditions here
        raise ValidationError('%s some error message' % value)
```

And then use this validator in your model

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_number])
```

Answer (score 1):

For better code reusability you can create custom `RangeIntegerField`

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models


class RangeIntegerField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        validators = kwargs.pop("validators", [])
        
        # turn min_value and max_value params into validators
        min_value = kwargs.pop("min_value", None)
        if min_value is not None:
            validators.append(MinValueValidator(min_value))
        max_value = kwargs.pop("max_value", None)
        if max_value is not None:
            validators.append(MaxValueValidator(max_value))

        kwargs["validators"] = validators

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can use this `Field` in your models

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_value = RangeIntegerField(min_value=42, max_value=451)
```

It plays well with both [django-forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) and [DRF's serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using postgres, you can use range fields to specify the range.
Check this: [Range Fields in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields)

Comment: you are referring the fields it for storing ranges, but the question was about constraints, which limit field value inside the range