# Change default constraint for SmallPositiveIntegerField

Tags: django

i want to change constraint that **`SmallPositiveIntegerField`** produces in Db during migration:

```
last_watched_episode smallint
        constraint archives_seasonmodel_last_watched_episode_check
            check (last_watched_episode >= 0),
```

I want to change `check (last_watched_episode >= 0)` to `check (last_watched_episode >= 1).`
Do you know where is the source code of this field in Django, that is in charge for making constraints?
I need it in order to create mixin for this field.
Thank you.

Point is to have only one constraint >=1 . If i did it via META class constraint, i would have 2 separete constraints >=0 and >= 1, which is makes no sence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django set range for integer model field as constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265698/6836173)

Comment: @wfehr  No, as in this instance i would have to make another one constraint. so that i will have >=1 and >= 0 constraints simultaniously. what i want is to adjust default field constraint in order to create only one constraint in DB. Default is >=0. I want  >= 1. It should be somewhere in source code.